# Date format in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet file and I need to convert the date column from this format: `Sun, May 4, 2014 4:30PM` to this format: `mm/dd/yyyy`. Basically, I need the date to be in a simple format and take out the “day” and “time”.

How can I do this?

Here is the link to the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s4EwFa7r0rdF24w3lAuasfcCw8kf1k4to4Y8dQdZjhI/edit#gid=1354673218

Comment: The Sheet linked doesn't have its permissions set correctly. I can't access it.

Comment: Does "the date column" actually contains dates, or just text? Impossible to tell since the spreadsheet isn't shared.

Comment: The date column has text in it. I just updated the link if you need to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix it for you:

```
=text(regexreplace("timestamp","^\w{3},",""),"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

you could also transform to remove the additional time parameter at the end with this:

```
=text(regexreplace(regexreplace("timestamp","^\w{3}, ",""), ", \d+:\d+\w+",""),"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

OR if your data consistently is formatted the way you did in your examples (with the commas present) you can simply do this:

```
=TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(C10,",(.*),"),"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Comment: Hi Aurielle, the formula is perfect! Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: follow up question please (I dont quite understand how the formula works), what if the date is in this format: Wed, Mar 4, 9:00AM and again I want it to be "MM/DD/YYYY", how should I modify the formula?

Comment: @Vee I updated my answers up top for you

Answer (score 2):

You can use "[Custom Date Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en)" to obtain mm/dd/yyyy format; however this requires the datetimes to be entered as datetimes — not as strings of text that look like date and time.

Usually, the difference is clear because under default formatting, datetimes are right-aligned while text is  left-aligned.

Comment: Hi AccioBooks, thanks for the help. I actually tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @Vee Oh, sorry.

Comment: I expanded your answer; otherwise it would likely be deleted after Low Quality Posts review. "This link might help you: [link]" is never a good answer.

Comment: @LiveForever Sorry. I probably should have put it as a comment.